# Fade In/Out and create/hide <DIV> with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, fadeout

I'm creating some  on runtime. For that I'm using this function:

```
function creatediv(id, html, left, top) {

if (document.getElementById(id)) 
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        fadeIn(id, 300);
    }
    else
    {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.setAttribute("class", "warningDiv"); 
        newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
        newdiv.innerHTML = html  + '<h1>(click to close)</h1>';
        newdiv.style.left = left;
        newdiv.style.top = top;
        newdiv.onclick=function(e) {
            fadeOutAndHide(id, 300);
        };  
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        fadeIn(id, 300);
    }

}
```

This function doesn't work with IE, and I don't know why. I get no error-warnings with this javascript.
These are de Fade-in functions:

```
function fadeOutAndHide (id,millisec)
{
    var object = document.getElementById(id).style;
    var opacStart = 100;
    var opacEnd=0;
    var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
    var timer = 0;

    for(i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
        setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
        timer++;
    } 

    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    if (opacEnd==0){
    elemento.style.display='none';
    }
}


function opacity(id, opacStart, opacEnd, millisec) {
    var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
    var timer = 0;

    if(opacStart > opacEnd) {
        for(i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
            setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
            timer++;
        }
    } else if(opacStart < opacEnd) {
        for(i = opacStart; i <= opacEnd; i++)
            {
            setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
            timer++;
        }
    }
}
```

Another problem that I have: The fadeout function doesn't work properly. The div fades, but the event "click" is fired when the div is hide. This is the function for fadeout:

```
function fadeOutAndHide (id,millisec)
{
    var object = document.getElementById(id).style;
    var opacStart = 100;
    var opacEnd=0;
    var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
    var timer = 0;

    for(i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
        setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
        timer++;

    } 

    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    if (i==1){
    elemento.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

So, what can I do to fix this issues?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the changeOpac function code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know what's wrong with your code, but I strongly recommend you use an existing javascript library (such as [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback) or [mootools](http://demos.mootools.net/Effects#)) which allows you to achieve things like fade in/out with one line of code and should work in most browsers.

Comment: Seconded. Nowadays using a library like jQuery will greatly simplify tasks like these and rapidly reduce your development time.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice, but my issue is not with jQuery, but with this code.

Comment: What I meant is: instead of coding your own effects, use an existing and proven library such as jQuery or mootools.

Comment: I know that, but I want to fix my code and not use jQuery. Hope you understand my position.